# How to cycle between open and closed firefox windows?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, windows-key

Trying to cycle between multiple open or closed Firefox windows fast instead of cycling through the virtual display with alt tab. Whats the quickest way/shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

`Windows logo key + Ctrl + Number` cycles between last active window

While looking into this l found

`Alt+Esc` but that only cycles open not closed windows

`Windows logo key + Number` does almost what l want but it opens up a menu listing all the Firefox windows  but l want cycle instantly instead of going through the menu listing

The other one l found is `Shift + Alt + Esc` cycles through every available windows currently running not being specific.